# How to write a JSON ZIP?

Tags: json, serialization, php-ziparchive

I serialize objects into JSON. On the fly I want to compress it in ZIP. ZIP file is created, but it turns out the damaged and empty. If you can tell, I'll be very grateful.

```
public void Write(List<Dictionary<string,string>> data)
{
    if (data.Count == 0) // If the collection is empty, then return
        return;
    PartNumber++; // In the archive are added many files. This is part of a single file
    string FullFileName = FolderWrite + FileName + ".zip";
    fsWrite = new FileStream(FullFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    ZipArchive archive = new  ZipArchive(fsWrite, ZipArchiveMode.Update);
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(FileName + ".part_" + PartNumber.ToString(), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    Stream s = entry.Open();
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Dictionary<string,string>>));
    ser.WriteObject(s, data);
    s.Close();
    fsWrite.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

need

```
archive.Dispose();
```

result

```
public void Write(List<Dictionary<string,string>> data)
        {

            if (data.Count == 0)
                return;
            PartNumber++;
            string FullFileName = FolderWrite + FileName + ".zip";
            ZipArchive archive;

            fsWrite = new FileStream(FullFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            archive = new  ZipArchive(fsWrite, ZipArchiveMode.Update);

            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(FileName + ".part_" + PartNumber.ToString(), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            Stream s = entry.Open();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Dictionary<string,string>>));
            ser.WriteObject(s, data);
            archive.Dispose();
            s.Close();
            fsWrite.Close();
        }
    }
```